# Buttons too many happened problem in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

```
struct Smaple:View {

    @State var a = false
    @State var b = false
     ...
    @State var l = false

    @State var name = ""

    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center){
        GeometryReader{ proxy in
            ScrollView(.vertical){
                VStack(alignment: .center){
                TextField("name", text: self.name)
                VStack{
                    Button(action:{self.a.toggle()}){Text("a")}
                    Button(action:{self.b.toggle()}){Text("b")}
                    ...
                    Button(action:{self.k.toggle()}){Text("l")}
                }
                }
            }
        }
        }.background(Color.blue)
    }
}
```

It's Ok when I had 10 buttons(a-j), but error happen when more than 10 (I designed 12 buttons).
Does anyone know how to do?

Comment: why you are not using List for that?

Comment: I try to make a more custom list, so not a priority use List.

Answer (score 2):

ViewBuilder only can hold 10 or less views. So if you have more than 10 views, use `Group` to divide it to less views in each group.

```
  Group{
       Button(action: {} ){ Text("")} 
        Button(action: {} ){ Text("")}  
        Button(action: {} ){ Text("")} 
        Button(action: {} ){ Text("")}
        Button(action: {} ){ Text("")} 
        Button(action: {} ){ Text("")}
     } // 6
  Group{
        Button(action: {} ){ Text("")} 
        Button(action: {} ){ Text("")}  
        Button(action: {} ){ Text("")} 
        Button(action: {} ){ Text("")}
        Button(action: {} ){ Text("")} 
        Button(action: {} ){ Text("")}} // 6
```

Answer (score 0):

In **`SwiftUI`** You can't add more than 10 child View. You can use **`Group`** for that. this will apply in **Form** also. :

```
VStack {
     Group {
         Button(action:{self.a.toggle()}){Text("a")}
         Button(action:{self.b.toggle()}){Text("b")}
     }
     Group{
        ...                   
        Button(action:{self.k.toggle()}){Text("l")}
     }
}
```